# Context-sensitive discontinuous font-locking in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

Im trying to setup font-locking for a major mode. Here is some example code:

```
USING: foo bar bar ;

IN: fuelcolors

TUPLE: font < super-class
    name
    size
    bold?
    italic?
    { foreground initial: COLOR: black }
    { background initial: COLOR: white } ;

TUPLE: rgb red green blue ;

: foobar ( seq -- seq )
  hello there { 1 2 3 } ;
```

The following symbols should be highlighted with some face (doesn't matter which, my problem is the matching part): name, size, bold?, italic?, foreground, background, red, green, blue. They represent names of slots in tuples.

I know a regexp wont do it because the matched region isn't continuous. italic? and foreground should be matched, but *not* the { character in between those symbols. So instead I thought I could author a font-lock matcher function, similar to the one Dmitri offered here: [Context-sensitive font-locking in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668225/context-sensitive-font-locking-in-emacs) for a very similar problem.

But afaict, his solution takes advantage of the fact that the "sequence" of items to highlight is inside paranthesises which is not the case here.

Font-lock has trouble with situations like these ([Unknown number of matches in regex and font-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120450/unknown-number-of-matches-in-regex-and-font-lock)), but I'm still hoping for some "good enough" solution even it if requires hacking font-lock internals.

Comment: I don't understand what is the rule that should be followed.  E.g. why not `bar`, `foo`, `fuelcolors`, ...?

Comment: Only words inside `TUPLE: .... ;` expressions should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with:

```
(,"\\(TUPLE\\):[ \n]+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\(?:[ \n]+<[ \n]+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\)?"
     (1 'factor-font-lock-parsing-word)
     (2 'factor-font-lock-type-name)
     (3 'factor-font-lock-type-name nil t)
     ("\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\|\\(?:{[ \n]+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)[^}]+\\)"
      ((lambda (&rest foo)
         (save-excursion
           (re-search-forward " ;" nil t)
           (1- (point)))))
      nil
      (1 'factor-font-lock-symbol nil t)
      (2 'factor-font-lock-symbol nil t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A matcher function seems like a good match for this.

I would use two functions, one that you can use to match `TUPLE` and to set the limits of the search of the members, and an inner matcher to find each element. The inner function could be written to be aware of the `{ name ... }` construct.

The trick is that the inner function is called *once for each element*, so there is never a situation where you have an unknown number of matches.

The rule would look something like:

```
'(my-match-a-tuple
  (1 'font-lock-keyword-name-face)    ;; Highlight the word TUPLE
  (my-match-tuple-member
   ;; Pre-match form (can be used move the point around and to set search limits)
   nil
   ;; Post-match form (can be used to move point around afterwords)
   nil
   (1 'font-lock-variable-face)))
```

You can look at my package for fontifying cmake scripts, it makes heavy use of matcher functions: https://github.com/Lindydancer/cmake-font-lock

Comment: Great that there *is* a solution. :) But getting the anchored matchers right is way to hard for me.